# How can i refresh a variable in a table already displayed in terminal. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I want to update a variable that's aready included inside a table displayed on Terminal.

I used Rich's Table class to display the table,

i've made an easy example for you to understand the problem.

[PHOTO with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqUie.png)

This is what i have in terminal, the ideea is to update only the '120', and to not print again the whole table with that value changed.

The code doesn't matter, i've printed a few lines for you just to understand what i need.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rich does not provide way to directly update individual cells within an already rendered table.